# How to restart android application programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

In one of my projects we have 
 `ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context)`
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix
when user was doing logout in the application
and the application is in production use 
now what I found this 
I don't understand this means I can use only for debug cases ,can't I use this for production cases or not?

`This should only be used for things like fundamental state changes in your debug builds (e.g., changing from staging to production).`
it is written in github

If no what is the alternative solution when I want to restart app on logout?

Comment: Why do you want to restart the app on a logout? Why not just start whatever activity that you want, such as the register/login one? You can also use your dependency inversion code (Dagger, Koin, etc.) to recreate all of your singletons.

Comment: I see but if I navigate to start activity how  all singletons would be recreated?

Comment: Ideally, you are using some dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.). In that case, you can tell the dependency inversion framework to reset your singletons (such as [these instructions for Koin](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/quick-references/modules-definitions/#dropping-definitions--modules---definitions-unload)). If you are not using a dependency inversion framework, you would need to reset your singletons by hand.

Comment: I am using dagger

Comment: But do you think I should recreate all my singletons?
or just navigating to LoginActivity would be enough

Comment: AFAIK, the typical approach is to set up a Dagger module that represents the singletons that are tied to the user identity. Then, you reset that module. Have another Dagger module (or modules) for singletons that do not depend on user identity and can remain intact despite the logout.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK 11 added [recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) method to activities.You can use it to restart the activity again .